Getting No HttpMessageConverter in postman response
public class DMSUploadImpl implements DMSUploadService {
    
    @Autowired
    private AccessUtill jwtUtil;
    
     @Value("${dms.upload}")
     String dmsUpload;
     
     @Value("${filevalidation}")
     String filevalidation;
     
     @Value("${dms.applicationName}")
     String applicationName;
     
     @Value("${dms.applicationID}")
     String applicationID;
     
     @Value("${dms.documentPath}")
     String documentPath;
     
     @Value("${dms.storageURL}")
     String storageURL;

     @Value("${filevalidation}")
     String fileValidationURL;
     
     
     private final Function<String, HttpHeaders> prepareHeader = (jwttoken) -> {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setBearerAuth(jwttoken);
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            return headers;
        };
      
        @Override
        public DMSOutputModel upload(MultipartFile file, UploadTemplateModel uploadTemplateModel, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

            String jwttoken = jwtUtil.getTokenthruHttpReq(request);
            String userID = "";

            if (jwttoken != null) {
                String employeeEmailID = jwtUtil.getUniqueId(jwttoken);
                userID = employeeEmailID.split("@")[0];
            }

            DMSOutputModel outresponse = new DMSOutputModel();
            
            try {
                String uploadFileValidationCall = fileValidationForUpload(jwttoken, file);
                if (uploadFileValidationCall.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains("file is valid")) {
                    
                    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

                    byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes();
                    String base64file = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileBytes);
                    
                    DMSInputModel uploadModel = new DMSInputModel(
                            applicationID,
                            applicationName,
                            base64file,
                            file.getOriginalFilename(),
                            documentPath,
                            storageURL,
                            userID);
                   

                    HttpEntity<DMSInputModel> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(uploadModel, prepareHeader.apply(jwttoken));

                    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

                    outresponse = restTemplate.exchange(dmsUpload, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, DMSOutputModel.class).getBody();
                    
                    if (outresponse.getDocumentID() != null && !outresponse.getDocumentID().isEmpty()) {
                        outresponse.setMessage("File Uploaded Successfully");
                        outresponse.setStatus("success");
                    }
                } else {
                    outresponse.setStatus("error");
                    outresponse.setMessage("Error during file upload: " + uploadFileValidationCall);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                outresponse.setStatus("failure");
                outresponse.setMessage("Error during file upload: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return outresponse;
        }

        public String fileValidationForUpload(String jwttoken, MultipartFile file) {
            String responseString = null;

            try {
                byte[] documentBytes = file.getBytes();
                long fileSizeInMB = file.getSize() / (1024 * 1024);

                if (fileSizeInMB > 50) {
                    responseString = "File size exceeds the limit";
                    return responseString;
                }

                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setBearerAuth(jwttoken);

                MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                bodyMap.add("appcode", "REORG");
                bodyMap.add("context", "REORG_AFC");
                bodyMap.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(documentBytes) {
                    @Override
                    public String getFilename() {
                        return file.getOriginalFilename();
                    }
                });

                headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

                HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);

                ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(fileValidationURL,
                        HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

                if (response.getBody().equalsIgnoreCase("File is Valid")) {
                    responseString = "File is valid";
                } else {
                    responseString = "File is not valid";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error during file upload: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return responseString;
            
        }

        public static boolean isValidFileExtension(MultipartFile file) {
            List<String> extensionList = Arrays.asList(".docx", ".xlsx", ".csv", ".pdf");
            String extension = "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
            boolean isValidExtension = false;

            isValidExtension = extensionList.stream().anyMatch(ext -> ext.equalsIgnoreCase(extension));
            return isValidExtension;
        }

@PostMapping(value = "/uploadtemplate", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> documentUpload(
             Integer applicationId, Integer categoryId, Integer subCategoryId, String quarter, Integer yearMonth,
             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, UploadTemplateModel uploadTemplateModel, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception, IOException {

         otrPortalService.uploadFile(applicationId, categoryId, subCategoryId, quarter, yearMonth, LocalDateTime.now());

         DMSOutputModel res = dmsUploadImpl.upload(file, uploadTemplateModel, request);

         Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
         response.put("status", res.getStatus());
         response.put("message", res.getMessage());
         response.put("documentName", res.getDocumentName());
         response.put("documentURL", res.getDocumentURL());
         response.put("documentID", res.getDocumentID());
         response.put("documentVersion", res.getDocumentVersion());

         return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
     }

In postman, in form data I am passing file key value pair.
Postman Response:
{
    "documentURL": null,
    "documentID": null,
    "documentName": null,
    "message": "Error during file upload: No HttpMessageConverter for DMSInputModel and content type \"multipart/form-data\"",
    "documentVersion": null,
    "status": "failure"
}

applicationID,applicationName,documentPath,storageURL,userID are configured in yml
HOW TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE?
I tried resolving but couldn't...
